# How to ask a question to confirm a negative situation?

Tags: questions, negation, question-tags

For example, I want to make sure that Tom was not in Professor X's class.  However, I can't ask:

> Wasn't Tom in Professor X's class last semester?

Because that means I think Tom **WAS** in Professor X's class.

Of course I can say:

> Tom wasn't in Professor X's class, was he?

But I would like to know if there's a more concise way to ask the question.

Comment: It might be a typo, but the first sentence assumes you think Tom **was** in Prof. X class last semester, not that he **is** now.

Comment: @nico: I've edited the question to clarify what I think @ablmf is asking.

Comment: If you're really keen to find the most concise way of asking, just say what you *think* is the case, with interrogative intonation. You don't actually *need* to tack "**, was he**" or "**, wasn't he**" on the end.

Comment: "Tom's not a mutant, right?"  ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I remember learning English in an East-European school; there were lots of exercises where we had to tack "was he", "wasn't he" -types at the end. Turns out nobody uses them, except for emphasis.

Comment: @Bogdan: I'm sure the number of exercises you had to do far outweigh the frequency of needing to use/understand it in real life (it's so testable), but it's not -nobody-.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only more concise way to ask it that I can think of is

> Was Tom in Professor X's class?

However, this changes what you're asking from confirming your belief that he was not to asking in a neutral fashion (that is, you have no a priori belief).

If you're wanting to keep it as a confirmation, something like your second option above is about as good as it gets:

> Tom wasn't in Professor X's class, right?

Comment: As pointed out in my Answer, your version is only neutral given neutral intonation and stress. And tacking **, right?** onto the end of an interrogative is hardly the right advice to give someone apparently looking for better command of English. It's 'downmarket' speech, to say the least. I'm disappointed both that OP accepted your Answer, and that several others upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

OP assumes that

**Wasn't Tom in Professor X's class?**

is a 'loaded' question. It implies the speaker thinks Tom was in the class, and therefore expects a positive confirmation from whoever is being asked.

But OP *also* assumes that

**Was Tom in Professor X's class?**

is a 'neutral' question, simply because that's the default way we parse the question when we read it. But it's a spoken question! To make it 'loaded' in the 'negative', the speaker simply stresses the first word **WAS**!

Answer (score 1):

"Tom wasn't in Professor X's class, right?"

Answer (score 0):

Does "Was Tom not in Professor X's class" ask what you need?  I think this is slightly different from the contraction "wasn't Tom..." and asks confirmation of Tom's non-presence.

Comment: I disagree: "Was Tom not in ..." and "Wasn't Tom in ..." are both asking for negation, i.e. they imply that you believe Tom *was* in the class.

Comment: @Martha: Well, my mileage varies here.  On a purely subjective level, I hear the first as requesting a simple statement of Tom's presence or presence, whereas the second implies some disbelief on the part of the questioner that Tom was not present.  That is to say, I tend to hear the questions "Was Tom in..." and "Was Tom not in..." as neutral, while I hear "Wasn't Tom in..." as looking for confirmation of a belief.  But, as I say the difference is slight and may be purely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that our friend Thomas was was not in Professor X's class.  Do you believe this is correct?

Comment: How is this *more* concise? :)